# Given matrix $A$ and column vector $x$, what is the derivative of $Ax$ with respect to $x$?

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus, jacobian

What is the correct answer of $\cfrac{\partial Ax}{\partial x}$, where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$(column vector).
[Here](https://web.stanford.edu/~jduchi/projects/matrix_prop.pdf)  in page 2, the answer is $$\nabla_{x} A x=\left[\begin{array}{c}{\nabla_{x} \tilde{a}_{1}^{T} x} \\ {\nabla_{x} \tilde{a}_{2}^{T} x} \\ {\vdots} \\ {\nabla_{x} \tilde{a}_{m}^{T} x}\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}{\tilde{a}_{1}} & {\tilde{a}_{2}} & {\cdots} & {\tilde{a}_{m}}\end{array}\right]=A^{T}$$
While [here](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/vecDerivs.pdf) in page 3, the answer is
$A$.
For me, I think the correct answer should be $A$. Is it right?

Comment: I think it depends on the layout convention: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions. So, both are correct depending on their convention.

Comment: Ever heard of the Jacobian?

Comment: Actually the first one is Jacobian matrix of the function $f:x\to Ax$, whereas the second one (and your guess) is the partial derivative with respect to $x$